# No plot with plotting function eulerr

Tags: r, eulerr

I am trying to create a Euler diagram with eulerr. With my own data no plot apears when I call `plot()`. I decided to run the example (https://github.com/jolars/eulerr) to see if I made any mistakes in my own code:

```
library(eulerr)
#From Wilkinson 2012
fit <- euler(c("A" = 4, "B" = 6, "C" = 3, "D" = 2, "E" = 7, "F" = 3,
               "A&B" = 2, "A&F" = 2, "B&C" = 2, "B&D" = 1,
               "B&F" = 2, "C&D" = 1, "D&E" = 1, "E&F" = 1,
               "A&B&F" = 1, "B&C&D" = 1),
             shape = "ellipse")
```

Then I run `plot(fit)` but still no plot appears. `fit$stress` and `fit$diagError` return expected values.

I am running it in RStudio (Version 1.3.959) on a Mac (OSX 10.12.6) with eulerr 6.1.0.
What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: When you say no plot appears, do you get any errors? Is the plot window size appropriately large? Are you using the base R GUI, or RStudio?

Comment: There are no errors, it just finishes without doing anything. The plot window is large but is stays empty.

Comment: Can you get any plots to show up? Did you try `dev.cur()` to check open devices? Or `dev.off()` to shut down devices?

Comment: works for me... try to write it to a pdf and see?

Comment: Writing it to a PDF worked! Thanks StupidWolf

Comment: Based on that, it seems that your graphics device in R is either misconfigured or not able to take the input from `eulerr`. Try with base R graphics, or in RStudion, "Zoom out"